# Is there an algorithm for determining the relevance of a text to a theme?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, text-mining, relevance

I want to know what can be used to determine the relevance of a page for a theme like games, movies, etc.

Is there some research in this area or is there only counting how many times some relevant words appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common choice is supervised document classification on bag of words (or bag of n-grams) features, preferably with tf-idf weighting.

Popular algorithms include Naive Bayes and (linear) SVMs.

For this approach, you'll need labeled training data, i.e. documents annotated with relevant themes.

See, e.g., [*Introduction to Information Retrieval*](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/), chapters 13-15.